# Entity Framework: how to use two records in one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm creating a simply database with Entity Framework using ASP.NET, i have class "Graphics" and class "InputOutput". I want to set in Initializer two records from InputOutput to Graphics one column.

Graphics.cs

```
public class Graphics
    {
        public int GraphicsID { get; set; }
        public int ProducerID { get; set; }
        public int InputOutputID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfConnection { get; set; }
        public string ProducerOfChipset { get; set; }
        public string TypOfMemory { get; set; }
        public string CoreSpeed { get; set; }
        public string MemoryClock { get; set; }
        public string MultiCardsTech { get; set; }
        public string HDCP { get; set; }
        public string CUDA { get; set; }
        public string VRReady { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfCooling { get; set; }

        public string Size { get; set; }

        public ICollection<InputOutput> InputOutput { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Producer> Producer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<LaptopProduct> LaptopProduct { get; set; }

    }
```

InputOutput.cs

```
public class InputOutput
    {
        public int InputOutputID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Graphics> Graphics { get; set; }
    }
```

And from Initializer:

```
var inputoutputs = new List<InputOutput>
            {
                new InputOutput { Name = "DVI"},
                new InputOutput { Name = "HDMI"},
                new InputOutput { Name = "VGA"}
            };

var graphics = new List<Graphics>
            {
                new Graphics { Name="GTX 1080", ProducerID=4, InputOutputID = "HERE ? What should i write to set 2 properties?" },
                new Graphics { Name="GTX 1070", ProducerID=4},
                new Graphics { Name="GTX 1080Ti", ProducerID=4},
            };
```

I want to display GTX1080 with e.g. two ports HDMI and VGA but i can only set one property to InputOutputID.

Comment: You need to setup a one to many relationship, see http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Actually it must be a many:many relationship because one gfxcard can have multiple outputs and one output type is used by many gfxcards.

Comment: Yup i know actually i set that in ICollection both classes but now how i can set this in code ? InputOutput = what ?? I don't know how to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initializer you can reference your previous list `inputoutputs`.

```
var graphics = new List<Graphics>
            {
                new Graphics { Name="GTX 1080", ProducerID=4, InputOutputID = inputoutput[0].InputOutputId, InputOutput = 
                   new List<InputOutput> { 
                           inputoutputs[0], inputoutputs[1] 
                   },
                new Graphics { Name="GTX 1070", ProducerID=4},
                new Graphics { Name="GTX 1080Ti", ProducerID=4},
            };
```

However, since this is a many to many, I'm not sure how the InputOutputID column is going to be used.  You need the junction table to get the items you need.

Here's an example of many to many in EF.  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Note, each table only have the collection to each other and none of the other table's ID attributes.

I also subscribe to making my many to many tables explicit in my ORM mappings.  AKA - I actually create the junction table in EF code.  Jimmy Bogard has a [great example](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/) and reasons for this.

Comment: Could i see it in SQL Managment or now i have many options to read properties and show them by ViewModel only?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: I set list that u showed me and now in SQL managment i have column and InputOutput = 1 , that was my quiestion what that list actually did? I don't see changes in SQL managment

Comment: If you mean the junction table, yes, you can see it in SMSS.  It's a real table created by EF, just without explicit creation in EF, your model doesn't "see it".  AKA - It's magic....  EF automatically uses it but you don't ever access it directly in your EF.  Hence, creating it yourself explicitly gives you the full range and that is what I like about it.

Comment: Gotcha, the list in the initializer should have your two items in the junction table that EF creates.  Look for a GraphicInputOutput table or vice versa....  In that table you should find your Graphics ID tied to the two InputOutput ID's.

Comment: So with this list can i show properties of my GTX on my website ? I mean i want to show GTX 1080 and on the right 3x HDMI, 1x DVI etc. ViewModel will see it? Or how can i call this magic list in view later ? :)

Comment: When you call your EF Model to get graphics card X, when you ask it for the inputoutput list, EF will automatically get the list via the junction table for you. Something like db.Graphics.Single(g=>g.Name=="GTX 1080").InputOutput.